# Configuring Quality of Service (QOS) Properties, Throttling, and Redelivery in Oracle SOA Suite

Tags: oracle, soa, throttling, qos

My team makes extensive use of Oracle SOA Suite for orchestration and integration of business processes between different systems.

During times of peak load, we're concerned about overloading the partner platforms that we integrate with.  We're looking into options for **throttling the requests made to external endpoints**.

I found the following article on Oracle's site which shows how to do this in some tool called "***Java CAPS***":

- [CAPS: Configuring Quality of Service (QOS) Properties, Throttling, and Redelivery](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E21454_01/html/821-2608/cnfg_bpel-qos-properties_r.html)

This seems to be the exact feature I need.  Unfortunately I'm coming up empty when it comes to finding this feature in Oracle SOA Suite 11g.

Answer (score 0):

Throttling is usually implemented by **ESB**. Please, check out the following links explaining howto enable throttling in OSB:

- [Service Throttling](http://oracle4servicebus.blogspot.com/p/service-throttling.html)
- [OSB 11g - Throttling](http://soawork.blogspot.com/2013/01/throttling-in-osb.html)

Regarding CAPS, I have never usedit but it looks like it is just another BPEL Proces editor. You can as well use e.g. jDeveloper if you want to enable throttling on the BPEL level, it should allow you to set the same set of parameters as CAPS.